# Connecting to home IP Camera from outside of home wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-camera

Note: I checked the answers under [Accessing IP cameras from outside network](https://superuser.com/questions/312311/accessing-ip-cameras-from-outside-network) but I could not understand. Forgive me for being this dumb :S. I thought using port forwarding or vpn to home network should solve this issue but it didnt.

I have **IP Camera Kaposev** (Hidden Wireless charger camera) that is accessible from the iOS app **HDWifiCamPro** when both the camera and my cellphone are connected to my wifi at home. It works OK. However, when I am trying to connect to the camera using the same app remotely (using the 4G network on my cellphone), the app fails to connect. Can you please tell me what I should do to connect to the camera from outside of my wifi?

What have I done so far?

- Using wireshark and my iphone connected to my Macbook (with RVI enabled and xcode installed), I was able to monitor the traffic between the Iphone and the camera. I see that the communication is going over UDP between ip_addr_camera:28888 and ip_addr_phone:20988
- The camera's username is: SOME_USERMAME and the password is: SOME_PASSWORD
- My public IP of wifi (gateway) is 218.201.55.211
- I created port forwarding in my router as following
- Port forwarding 1: Name: Testcam Protocol:UDP WAN_port:20988 LAN_port:28888 Destination_IP:ip_addr_camera Destination_MAC:MAC_CAM
- Port forwarding 2: Name: Testcam2 Protocol:UDP WAN_port:28888 LAN_port:20988 Destination_IP:ip_addr_camera Destination_MAC:MAC_CAM
- I have enabled the VPN service in my router setting and created a VPN on my cellphone. Hence, when I connect to the VPN on my cellphone, I get the public IP address of 218.201.55.211 and I get a LAN IP for my device as well.

After these steps, I am lost. I am new to the whole networking thing, I will really appreciate it if you can guide me on what more should I do to be able to view this camera remotely. Is there any easy way to access the stream remotely? I do not know if my camera is ONVIF compatible or not

I am unable to access the camera from (With or WITHOUT vpn) udp://ip_addr_camera:28888 or 20988

**Update**: Turns out that I am unable to ping my other devices on LAN when connected with VPN. Following is the configuration that I am using

**VPN Server settings with in router (Technicolor wifi router plus v3 )**

- Local IP: 192.168.1.245
- Remote IP Start: 192.168.1.246
- Remote IP End: 192.168.1.253

**DHCP Settings**

- Local Device: 192.168.1.1
- Network address: 192.168.1.0
- DHCP Start address: 192.168.1.64
- DHCP End address: 192.168.1.243

**Static IPs Settings**

- Camera: 192.168.1.244
- MAC book: 192.168.1.49
- Iphone: 192.168.1.246

**VPN Client settings**

- Server address: My public ip of home network
- Type: L2TP over IPSec
- Username: MY_VPN_USER
- Password: MY_VPN_PASS
- Shared Secret: SOME_SECRET
- Send all traffic: True
- DNS Servers: As provided by device for WAN (2.248.248.2,
  2.248.248.248)

**Update 2**: I can ping the devices now from the inside the wifi lan connected laptop to external vpn connect iphone. I can also ping the lan connected camera ip address from my vpn connected external device.
BUT i am unable to connect to the camera though its app HDWIFICam pro still :(

Comment: `unable to access the camera from udp://ip_addr_camera:28888 or 20988` ... what about `218.201.55.211:28888`?

Comment: Are you able to access other LAN devices (e.g. the Macbook) through the VPN?

Comment: You have your port forwarding rule wrong. The source port you saw in wireshark (`20988`) is not relevant. The camera appears to listen on port `28888` but I question if there are additional ports required. In any case, the WAN port and LAN port in your forwarding rule should both be `28888`.  This says all packets arriving on your public IP destined to port `28888` will forward to the internal camera IP also on port `28888`. Then you need to put in your public IP for the camera address in the app when you are outside your local network. VPN is a different setup - no forwarding required.

Comment: Be aware that port forwarding to your camera is really insecure. These devices are notoriously insecure and often have software flaws which lead to them becoming zombie devices for attackers and compromise privacy and security. Your VPN solution is much safer, but your question doesn’t provide enough details to troubleshoot VPN - it doesn’t even mention the router model or configuration you used

Comment: @user1686 you are correct here, I am unable to access other devices on the LAN. My cam is on IP 192.168.1.244 
When I am using the VPN, even though my public ip address becomes the same as my home network public ip address, and I am able to connect to my router's LAN ip address as well for admin settings, but when I am pinging the ip address of the cam OR of my other devices, I get the following error.

PING 192.168.1.244 (192.168.1.244): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

Can you please tell me what should I do now? I will update question with vpn/router configuration

Comment: When you connect to the VPN, does the router assign you an address from the same subnet as the LAN devices, or a separate subnet? If you try to ping a connected VPN device's address from a LAN device, does it show up in `arp -a` / `arp -an` afterwards?

Comment: The VPN connected device (Iphone using iOS) shows the ip address 192.168.1.246, which corresponds to the Remote IP Start address from VPN Server (router).

I am unable to ping even the Iphone from wifi-LAN connected macbook or vice versa

Comment: @user1686 I did the ping to 192.168.1.247 (IP for VPN Client device, iphone) from my laptop which is within the wifi lan devices. 

While doing this I ran arp -an and got 
 (192.168.1.1) at a4:91:b1:2c:13:56 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.50) at 5e:f2:27:ca:f8:6d on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.127) at ec:b5:fa:2d:3:36 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.202) at 2c:95:69:2:a5:68 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.221) at a0:80:69:88:bf:71 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.247) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet].

Comment: As you can see last ip, of iphone, is shown as incomple

Comment: That honestly sounds like an issue with the way the router implements VPN – if it wants to assign LAN IP addresses to VPN devices then it's supposed to implement "Proxy ARP" for them; is that an option somewhere? If not – is it an option to make the VPN use a separate subnet (separate address range) from the LAN?

Comment: @user1686 thank you very much. I think i will try changing the router as well. I am thinking about getting ASUS RT-AC59U V2 instead.

But I tried enabling proxy Arp on the current router,  I am able to ping the devices, but every few other seconds i get the timeout. Any ideas, why the timeout when I am able to now ping the devices after proxy arp?

Answer (score 1):

##### Forward Public to Private

Your goal is to redirect (forward, remap, etc.) incoming requests for `[public_IP]:XXXX` to `[private_IP]:XXXX` (**`XXXX`** to **`XXXX`**).

##### You are changing the port!

What you are describing in both your forwarding examples is taking incoming requests for `[public_IP]:XXXX` and forwarding them to `[private_IP]:YYYY` (**`XXXX`** to **`YYYY`**).

The mobile application is sending to port **`XXXX`** the same port on which the camera is listening.  Unfortunately the router is redirecting the traffic to an unused port **`YYYY`** so the requests time out.

##### Just remap the destination IP

So, if you remap **only** the destination IP and keep the **same port** the packets will arrive at their intended destination.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I did try this, but then when I checked through wireshark, I saw that the IP Cam had changed it port to a different one.

I am wondering if I should change my router. Please also see my Update2 in the answer regarding the vpn